# Exporting resized pictures from Excel to PowerPoint 2010

Tags: excel, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, vba

I've created a code that copies pictures from Excel to a new PowerPoint presentation. The code works fine for MS Office 2016, but **not** MS Office 2010. Particularly, a picture that is exported to PowerPoint will not be resized in `.pptx` for 2010.

How can I fix this?

Here is the problematic piece of code that does not work in MS 2010:

```
    Application.Goto Reference:="Full_Account_Performance"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    PPPres.Slides(x).Shapes.PasteSpecial

    On Error Resume Next                
    With PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 
        .ScaleHeight 0.435, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft 
        'Powerpoint 2010 ingnors it... but in 2016 it is fine
        .Left = 10
        .Top = 55
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerPoint 2010, it sometimes skips the lines after you paste a picture using `Shapes.PasteSpecial` command (they are not skipped, just the code runs them before it completes to paste the Picture).

There is a work-around, you can add a delay of a second, and the code will work (the lines below won't be skipped).

The code below will set an `Object` to the pasted picture in PowerPoint, and later just modify `myShape` properties.

**Note**: The code below uses ***Late Binding***, but it will work also for ***Early Binding***.

**Code**

```
Dim PPPres                              As Object
Dim PPSlide                             As Object
Dim myShape                             As Object

' set the slide object - x is the slide number
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(x)  

' Set an Object to the Pasted PowerPoint picture
Set myShape = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(0, msoFalse) ' ppPasteDefault = 0
With myShape
    ' it skips the lines below, add a delay
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    .ScaleHeight 0.435, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    .Left = 10
    .Top = 55
End With
```

Comment: Hey Rado, 
that is crazy! When i applied what you wrote it worked exactly right!
thanks a lot and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the issue:

```
With PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
```

Try:

```
With PPPres.Slides(x).Shapes(y)
```

where y = the picture you've just pasted. Since you're not setting a reference to it, you may need to iterate through the shapes in the slide to find which shape it is.

Comment: hi, that worked but not for all pictures that i exported BUT i must say i moved on a bit! in total i need to export 22 pics. i pic one per slide. i set y = 1 and in the loop i also did a simple calculus y=y+1 BUT only the second picture was resized... this is very strange as all pics are exported with no problems to particular slides, so a cycle that i have ->works, but it resizes only second slide... Any idea why? when i put X instead of Y does not work for all neither...

Comment: I think Shai Rado nailed it. If their solution works reliably don't forget to give their answer a tick. Either way, glad to hear.